# OpenGL functions undefined with glew

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opengl, glew

So, I'm trying to use glew, and have this weird problem, where all openGL functions are undefined, and produce LNK2019. All openGL constants(like GL_TRUE) are defined and work, and glews own functions(like glewInit) work, and glewInit does return GLEW_OK. glewExperimental seems to be also unresolved(and produces LNK2001)

I have set up a dummy project, witch has added the directory of glew32.lib to additional library directories, and glew32.lib to additional dependencies. I have also put glew32.dll in the project folder.

I downloaded glew form their website as precompiled binaries, and libraries and dlls are all 32-bit versions, since I'm compiling to Win32 platform.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on windows 10. I successfully used glew on windows 7 and VS 2013, but after the upgrade, I haven't got it to work.

EDIT:
Here's the error form my attempted dummy build:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetIntegerv@8 referenced in function _main
```

Comment: how about you post an error output from an attempted build?

Comment: `glGetIntegerv` is not a glew function. It's OpenGL function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As doron said, you need to link opengl32.lib. This is from the glew documentation:

> Remember to link your project with glew32.lib, glu32.lib, and opengl32.lib on Windows and libGLEW.so, libGLU.so, and libGL.so on Unix (-lGLEW -lGLU -lGL).

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL comes as a library, you must link the library in in order to use OpenGL otherwise expect to get linker errors.